# Recording perf files with symbols for analysis on a different system (cross architecture)

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, perf

I'm recording perf traces on an embedded target which I want to evaluate on a desktop host using hotspot. However, as far as I can tell this means the the desktop has to set up a complete sysroot for the embedded target to read the symbols correctly.

Is there a way to create stand-alone perf.data files or hotspot files that I can just send to people for evaluation without having to set up a sysroot? Heaptrack can do this, I wonder what the problem for perf would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `perf archive`.

```
[user@MachineA]$ perf record --debuginfod SomeCommand --some --arguments
# Creates `perf.data`, containing profiled data.

[user@MachineA]$ perf archive
# Creates `perf.data.tar.bz2`, containing object files and debug symbols.
```

```
[user@OtherMachine]$ mkdir ~/.debug

[user@OtherMachine]$ tar xvf perf.data.tar.bz2 -C ~/.debug

[user@OtherMachine]$ perf report
# Reads `perf.data`, using objects and symbols extracted from the archive.
```

If you pull in a lot of libraries, expect the archive to be proportionally large and possibly take a long time to create.

---

If `perf archive` isn't available for whatever reason, or if you'd like to modify the output format, you can try downloading and using the `perf-archive.sh` Bash script separately from the Linux source tree:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/perf/perf-archive.sh

Comment: Now THAT looks useful.

Comment: It shows an error perf: 'archive is not a perf-command. See 'perf --help".       But the command is listed there!

Comment: @Desperado17 Huh. That's weird. Is it possible you're using a special build of `perf` that stripped it out? But in [`perf.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/perf/perf.c), "archive" *is* actually set to `NULL`… Actually, I think I think the subcommand just invokes a Bash script to `tar` a bunch of stuff. Try downloading and using it separately: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/perf/perf-archive.sh